# Will multiple data files cause website to run slower, even if they aren't being used by web app?

Tags: javascript, html, json, web-applications

Let's say I have a web application, and its function is to display data from a fairly large JSON file.  The web page is one folder on my desktop (a data folder storing JSON files, HTML file, CSS folder storing CSS scripts, and JavaScript folder storing JS scripts) that I've pushed onto GitHub.  Very straightforward.

```
"My application folder"
- css folder
    -style.css
- data folder 
    -json1
    -json2
    -json3
    -json4
    -json5
    -json6
- javascript folder
    -main.js
-index.html
```

My question is this: will storing many large JSON files (each has different data) in the data folder cause my website to run slower, even if only one JSON is being rendered by the webpage at any given time?  Does the loading time of the page increase if there's more data files in the data folder, regardless of whether they are actively being used by the web app and loaded into the DOM?

I'm asking because I'm thinking of storing many JSON files in the data folder, and dynamically loading different JSON files into the webpage based on what the user does. But - I don't want to use this approach if it's going to cause the webpage to load extremely slowly.

Yes - I know I could use a database in the cloud like PostGres, etc.  But for now, I would like to avoid using a database if possible.

Comment: I don't see why it would slow the website. The "speed" is much linked to your internet bandwith (big files and small bandwith => slow). All servers are able to process large files.

Comment: is the speed linked to files being actively rendered in the browser, or files stored on the webpage (even if not being used / rendered)?

Answer (score 0):

It will not slow your website because the files are not in use other then taking up space which could affect performance if the disks starts be coming full.